# slidetoggle with effect

Tags: jquery

I have the following code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function shownavall()
{
$('#shownavall').slideToggle('slow', function() {
 $('.otherlink').toggle(function(){
    $(this).css('background-position', '0px 0px');
     }, function(){
    $(this).css('background-position', '25px 0px');
 });
  });

}
</script>
```

when I try to call the function the function works on the `slidetoggle` part. but does not change the `css` for `.otherlink` I want to know why? and how to fix it?

I tried to do it by using a conditioning statement, here is my code : (this code does not work at all!)

```
function shownavall()
{
$('#shownavall').slideToggle('slow', function() {
if ($('.otherlink').css('background-position') == '25px 0px')
{
$(.otherlink).css('background-position', '0px 0px');
}
else 
{
$(.otherlink).css('background-position', '25px 0px');
}
  });
}
```

I am 100% sure that the mistake is in my Jquery code. so please do not ask about the html or the css.

Comment: @shnisaka please post the html also or just [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) it...

Comment: I have already answered my own question.

Comment: i have made edit . check it if it is doing for u!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function shownavall()
{
$('#shownavall').slideToggle('slow', function() {
if ($('.otherlink').css('background-position') == '25px 0px')
{
$('.otherlink').css('background-position', '0px 0px');
}
else 
{
$('.otherlink').css('background-position', '25px 0px');
}
  });
}
```

Comment: what is difference b/w ur posted quest nd this ans? Aren't they same?

Comment: ('.otherlink') instead of (.otherlink)

Answer (score 0):

i think in css "background-position" is correct instead of "backgroundposition".
Also background -position changes the position of background not the position of element itself so you have to use position attribute.

```
      <script type="text/javascript">

  function shownavall()
    {
     $('#shownavall').slideToggle('slow', function() {
     $('.otherlink').toggle(function(){
  $(this).css({'position':'absolute','left':'100px','top':'150px'});

      }, function(){
    $(this).css({'position':'absolute','left':'0px','top':'0px'});
  });
    });

  }

     </script>
```

Comment: have u tried alert! in the code. is it working? if working then try $(this).attr("style",'background-position:0px 0px');